# Does Fortification stack with Unusual Anatomy?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, sorcerer

Armor can be enchanted with the Fortification ability, which provides 25/50/75% chance to avoid critical hits or sneak attacks. An aberrant sorcerer of 9th level or higher gets Unusual Anatomy, which provides a 25% chance to avoid critical hits or sneak attacks (50% at 13th level).

If a 13th level aberrant sorcerer wore armor with medium fortification, would they be effectively immune to crits/sneak attacks because the benefits stack? Or does the highest value win out?

Comment: Absent information to the contrary, [answers'll be the same for *Pathfinder* as *3.5* .](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97676/8610)

Answer (score 2):

In pathfinder, bonuses with the same type or with the same name do not stack unless specifically described as doing so (e.g. dodge bonuses to AC).

Sometimes it might look like so: for instance, the armor bonus of an armor seems to stack with the armor bonus from the *magic vest* spell; in reality the spell provides an enhancment bonus to the piece of armor and the now-larger armor bonus from the armor is compared with other sources of armor bonuses, such as the *mage armor* spell (much like an enhancement bonus to strength stacks with your strength to determine your melee attack).

In this case, since neither Fortification nor Unusual Anatomy say that they stack, they don't. You need to take the highest value.

Comment: Enhancement bonuses do not stack. Only Dodge bonuses to AC are specifically called out as always stacking. There are many effects that increase Enhancement bonus, but if you have two +6 Dexterity (enhancement) wondrous items, you only have +6 and if you somehow have two armors equipped, one +1 and the other +3, you have the higher AC+3.

Comment: @Ifusaso Yes. Two enhancement bonuses would not stack.

Comment: @AshRandom are you trying to convey that an enhancement bonus to Armor AC stacks with Armor AC (ditto for Shield AC and Natural AC)?

Comment: @Zachiel feel free to edit this

Comment: I still don' t think the two effect follow the rules for stacking _bonuses_, but I think it's clearer what you meant, now.

Answer (score -1):

The two effects do not interact, because none says so. Roll both separately, it's diminishing returns but it's better than nothing (except if you spent resources instead of having both as a secondary result of your build).